# Automatic model vizualization in R

Tags: r

Dears,

is there any `R packages` for quick ML or Classical model vizualizations?
By this I mean HTML, Shiny or other wrappers for `Explanatory model analysis`, `model diagnostics`, `scenarios`, etc.

Could you please share your experience and the best practices?

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ ?

Comment: This may be useful: [LIME](https://lime.data-imaginist.com/index.html)

Comment: rstudio has a rapid development visualization app, i.e. the flexdashboard package: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [rBokeh](https://hafen.github.io/rbokeh/articles/rbokeh.html) that is just a wrapper for python's [Bokeh](https://bokeh.org) lib.